# How to insert assembly code via LLVM?

Tags: assembly, clang, llvm

I am pretty new to LLVM. I need to do a transformation pass where before every basic block, I need to insert this instruction 'mov $0, r15'.
Assume I know how to iterate across Basic Blocks, my struggle is inserting this assembly code.

Can anyone write some sample code? or point me to some examples?

Answer (score 2):

First, a quick note. LLVM has both `BasicBlock`s and `MachineBasicBlock`s. The former is a block of IR `Instruction`s. The latter is a block of target-specific `MachineInstr`uctions. You want to be working with the latter.

As for actually inserting instructions, that's easy enough using BuildMI (completely untested code -- just demonstrating the general principle):

```
TargetInstrInfo *TII = ...;          // An instance of X86InstrInfo or similar

for (MachineBasicBlock *MBB = ...) {
    DebugLoc dl;                     // Empty debugging location
    BuildMI(MBB, MBB.begin(), dl, TII->get(X86::MOV64ri32),
            X86::R15).addImm(0);
}
```

The documentation for BuildMI is here: http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/namespacellvm.html#a980570dc1410d4ef53806f82028ca381
(Note that there are many many overloads -- check which one applies to you)

It may be the case that this is not actually the instruction that you want to use, in which case look up the table of instructions here: https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/master/lib/Target/X86/X86InstrInfo.td

Similarly there's a table of registers here: https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/master/lib/Target/X86/X86RegisterInfo.td

Answer (score 0):

Create a C source with inline assembly, compile it to LLVM bitcode with `clang -c -emit-llvm`, then run `llc -march=cpp out.bc`. This would produce you C++ source with calls to LLVM API required to generate input bitcode file.